# How i can get the context of started activity

Tags: java, android, android-context, android-dialog, window-managers

I'm trying to show a custom dialog in non-activity class for that i need the context of the foreground running activity which I did started from the main activity. 
i get this exception when i run

```
Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

I did use the context of a service but it not work

**Cod of non-activity class**

```
public void Confirmation_dialog_V2(ReportEvent e){
    try{
        Log.e("Bugreport","Confirmation");
        Log.e("Bugreport","event: "+e.getEventDescription());
        getRecording_service().stopRecording();
        context=  getRecording_service().getBaseContext();
        context.setTheme(R.style.CustomTheme);
        Log.e("Bugreport","get context");
        if(context != null) {
            Log.e("Bugreport","context not null");
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.e("Bugreport","in run block");
                    LovelyStandardDialog dialog =new LovelyStandardDialog(context, LovelyStandardDialog.ButtonLayout.VERTICAL);
                    dialog.setTopColorRes(R.color.indigo);
                    dialog.setButtonsColorRes(R.color.darkDeepOrange);
                    dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_assignment_white_36dp);
                    dialog.setTitle("Confirm_interaction");
                    dialog.setMessage("Interaction:"+e.getEventDescription());

                    dialog.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                        }
                    });
                    dialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            }
                    });
                    dialog.setNeutralButton("Contine", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {


                        }
                    });
                    Log.e("Bugreport","showing");
                    dialog.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

}
```

so i need the context of the activity in the foreground with I did started from the main activity.

**Main activity**

```
 Intent App = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(BugReport.getInstance().getPackageName());
    App.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    App.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    App.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(App);
```

Comment: You can pass context as parameter in that method

Answer (score 1):

You can use Constructor for this problem.When you declare java class in your MainActivity java class that time Add Context with it.

As per your code you have Added ReportEvent , just Add context with that.like below:

```
public void Confirmation_dialog_V2(Context context,ReportEvent e){

//your code

}
```

If you will directly add Context in java class then it will show error in Main Java class where you declare JavaClass.and when you Add context there,error will disappear Automatically.

After it all you can use that context anywhere in that Java class.Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Confirmation_dialog_V2(ReportEvent e,Context context)
```